# P.d.f. of $XY$, where $X, Y$ are independent uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I tried to change the variables:

Let $U=XY$ and $V=Y$; so then the Jacobian is $1/v$.

So joint pdf $g(u,v) = f(x,y)\cdot (1/v) = 1/v$

Would you then integrate over $v$ from $0$ to $1$ to get the p.d.f., of just $U$?

However this gives infinity.

Comment: I accidentally moused over Leave Open and did not intend to make that vote. This is, in fact, a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your joint pdf is wrong.  You should get

$$g(u,v) =  I(0<v<1) I(0<u<v)/v,$$

where $I$ is the indicator function.  Then just do

$$\int_u^1 \frac{1}{v} dv = [\log v]_u^1= -\log u,$$

which for $0<u<1$ is the density of $XY$.

Comment: Why do you integrate from u to 1? Is it the same as from 0 to u?

Comment: Because for $v<u$ the indicator function and hence the density function equals zero.  Note that $V$ cannot be less than $U$ by construction.

Comment: I understand; thank you!